# Find and style multiple strings efficiently

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I can search and change the styling of all occurrences of a specific string with indexOf(), like so:

```
var links = [...document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")];

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  if (links[i]["href"].indexOf("dog") == -1) {
    continue;
  }
  links[i].style["color"] = "green";
}
```

But how would I change all occurrences of multiple given strings, i.e. "dog" AND "cat"?

I wasn't expecting this to work but tried it anyway:

```
var links = [...document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")];
var pets = ["dog", "cat"];

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  if (links[i]["href"].indexOf(pets) == -1) {
    continue;
  }
  links[i].style["color"] = "green";
}
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `some`:

```
if (!pets.some(pet => links[i].href.includes(pet))) {...}
```

Or use a regex:

```
if (!(new RegExp(pets.join("|")).test(links[i].href))) {...}
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for but I can't figure out how to make it work with my snippet

Comment: You should be able to just replace the `if` condition with the one in my answer. Is it throwing any errors?

Comment: No errors - it just breaks. When I remove the continue, all the links are green.

Comment: Place the `links[i].style.color = "green"` *inside* the `if` statement - much better practice and easier to debug it. Does that work? (e.g. remove `continue`)

Comment: Fixed it! All I had to do was add an ! before pets

Comment: Oh, that makes sense - sorry, I completely missed that. I'll edit my answer. If it fixed your problem, please accept it.

Comment: @JackBashford, yes this is a nice clean solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

This changes all the links green that the href doesn't contain various pet names.

```js
var links = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.body.getElementsByTagName("a"));

    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        const href = links[i].href;
        const re = /(dog|cat|horse|cow|etc)/g
        if (!re.test(href)) {
          links[i].style.color = "green";
        }
    }
```

```html
<a href="http://www.thisurl-cat.com">link 1 cat</a>
<a href="http://www.thisurl.com">link 2</a>
<a href="http://www.thisurl-horse.com">link 3 horse</a>
<a href="http://www.this-dog-url.com">link 4 dog</a>
<a href="http://www.thisurl.com">link 5</a>
```

Comment: But what if `pets` is extremely long? Would you like to copy/paste that condition lots of times?

Comment: @Jack Bashford Exactly. I'm looking to add about 20 "pets" to this.

Comment: @King_Lady, I edited my answer.  But what exactly are you trying to do?  If the href contains any of the pet names, then turn the link(s) green?

Comment: @BryanElliot The document contains links, and some of them contain certain strings (for example) "dog", "cat", etc, I want all the links containing those strings to be targeted. I have no experience with regex but I tried your edit and it changes all the links EXCEPT those listed. lol

Comment: @King_Lady, Oh ok, then just change the condition..  Like: `if (!re.test(href))`  Try that. :)

Comment: @BryanElliott That did it!

Comment: @King_Lady, Great! Glad it was helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a second `for` loop to check each index of `pets`:

```js
var links = [...document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")];
var pets = ["dog", "cat"];

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < pets.length; j++) {
    if (links[i]["href"].indexOf(pets[j]) !== -1) {
      links[i].style["color"] = "green";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#cat">cat</a>
<a href="#dog">dog</a>
<a href="#person">person</a>
```

Note, however, that **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** will return `-1` when there's **not** a match, so you'll want to only set the colour to green if the `indexOf()` is *not* equal to `-1` (as is shown above).

Comment: Adding additional for loops is exactly what I was hoping to avoid. I have about 20 more "pets" I'm looking to add to the list